# Usage of F# async workflows

Tags: asynchronous, f#

As this question is huge, I will give my view on this question so that you can simply tell me whether I am right or not. If not, where to correct. If my view is superficial, please present an overview of F# async usage. In mu understanding, to write async program, you need to put async code into "async" block like async{expression}, and use "let!" or "use!" to bind names to primitives, then you need to use method to run this async expression like "Async.Run". In addition, you can use exception handling to deal with exception, and cancellation to cancel when necessary. I also know there are several primitives that defined in F# core libraries, and F# extension of I/O operation. I just need to make sure the relation between these things. If you think my view on async workflows is superficial, please give an overview usage like what I have mentioned above. Thank you very much!

Comment: This question is imprecise. Could you clarify what it is you want?

Comment: whether my opinion on usage of F# async workflows is right, and how to improve. and the relations among primitives, F# extension of I/O operation, start run methods like "Async.Run" .Thank you

Answer (score 7):

This question *is* huge, so at best, I can highlight some ideas and point you to learning resources and examples.

The description in the question isn't wrong (though there is no Async.Run function). But the main point about Asyncs is *how* they execute and *why* the way they execute is useful.

- An `async` block defines a piece of code that becomes an `Async<'T>` object, which can be seen as a computation that can be executed at a later time. The Async returns an object of type `'T` when its execution has completed -- if it has neither failed nor been cancelled.
- `let!`, `do!` and `use!` are used inside of an `async` block to run another Async and, in the cases of `let!` and `use!`, bind its result to a name inside the current async. Unlike for example normal `let`, which simply binds any value to a name, the versions with an exclamation mark explicitly "import" the *result* of another async.
- When an Async depends on another and waits for its result, such as with a `let!` binding, it normally does not block a thread. Asyncs utilize the .NET thread pool for easy parallel execution, and after an Async completes that another Async depends on, a continuation runs the remainder of the dependent Async.
- The [Async functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370232.aspx) offer many ready-made ways to run Asyncs, such as `Async.Start`, which is a simple dispatch of an Async with no result, `Async.RunSynchronously`, which runs the Async and returns its result as if it were a normal function, `Async.Parallel`, which combines a sequence of Asyncs into one that executes them in parallel, or `Async.StartAsTask`, which runs an Async as an independent task. Further methods allow composition of Asyncs in terms of cancellation, or explicit control over continuation after an exception or cancellation.

Asyncs are very useful where waiting times are included: otherwise blocking calls can use Asyncs to not block execution, for example in I/O bound functions.

The best introductions to F# Asyncs I know are written, or co-written, by Don Syme, the lead designer of F#:

- The chapter *Reactive, Asynchronous, and Parallel Programming* in the book *Expert F#*
- A [blog post with examples for asyncronous agents](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/02/15/async-and-parallel-design-patterns-in-f-part-3-agents.aspx)
- The [blog post introducing Asyncs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2007/10/11/introducing-f-asynchronous-workflows.aspx) in late 2007